# How can a Azure SQL query return the old value and new value of a database entry?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a situation I've not encountered before.

Running two different queries in Microsoft Azure SQL against a dataset, one returns as record with the old value before an update, and the other query returns the new updated value.

I've tried forcing both queries to run with no index, and it's still the same result.

How can this happen, and where should I start looking to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

By default Azure SQL Database uses READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation.  So if you update a row in a transaction then the transaction's session and any session using dirty reads would see the updated-but-not-committed value, while any other session using READ COMMITTED or SNAPSHOT isolation level would see the pre-transaction version of the row.